# How to use application.serve in jaggery.js?

Tags: wso2, jaggery-js

The documentation has [little information](http://jaggeryjs.org/documentation.jag?api=application) on this subject. If I copy application.serve declaration into my script, I get an error:

> Cannot find function serve in object [object Application]

The script file is very simple:

```
<%
application.serve(function(request, respond, session) {});
%>
```

I found a presentation with an example on [slide #23](http://www.slideshare.net/madhukaudantha/java-script-everywhere40), but it says I have to require a router. When I do this I get another error.

**How is "application.serve" to be used in a proper way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`application.serve` is the centralized entry point in proposed [front-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) model. This new model is not finalized and still in an architectural review state.

Under the current model you can directly write function body logic inside Jaggery code block.
`request`, `respond`, `session` are visible to the code section as top level variables.

eg:

```
<html>
  <body>
   <%
     print("Method : " + request.getMethod() + "<br/>");
   %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This feature looks like the Express framework in Node.js or like the Bullet framework in PHP. It would be nice to have this feature.